# Button for Updating a Database single entry with PHP AJAX Call

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, mysql, ajax

For Future Readers, this was my first question and the answer has been found (read comments and replies below):

First of all, i've searched in Stackoverflow and i didn't found an answer for a similar problem.

i would like to link a html Button (among many buttons) with a JQuery function. The function shall execute AJAX method like so :

HTML Code in a separated file index.php:

```html
<button id="submitbtn" type="button" class="btn btn-success">UPDATE</button>
```

JQuery Function :

```js
    $('#submitbtn').on('click', function(){
        var id = $(this).data('id');

        $.ajax({
            url: 'includes/updatequery.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {id:id},
            success: function(data){
                if (data) {
                console.log("updated");
                } else {
                    $('#error').load("custom/static/error.html");
                }
            },
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
                $('#error').html("oops" + errorThrown);
            }
        });
    });
```

Here is the PHP file that should be called by AJAX Method :

```php
<?php
include("src/db.php");
$query = "UPDATE mytable SET job='completed' WHERE id=id";
mysqli_query($conn, $query);
  
?>
```

The problem is that i CANNOT link the ID of the clicked button (because there are many buttons) to the ID of the Database Entry in order to update the Data in the Database according to this specific button.

---

Now i would like to have the results updated LIVE after updating the Database.

This is the PHP code that output menu items (items stored in the same Database table as before) and in front of every menu item, a badge should be displayed (with a value within it : "completed" or "not completed") :

```
<?php 
            foreach($data as $d) {
              $id = $d['id'];
              $mystatus = $d['status'];
            ?>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link clickable blueMenuItem" id="nav-location" data-id="<?php echo $d['id']; ?>">
                  <i class="nav-icon fas <?php echo $d['icon']; ?>"></i>
                  <p><?php
                    echo $d["title"];
                    if ($d['type'] == "job") { ?>
                      <span id="updatedicon" class="right badge <?php if($mystatus == "completed"){echo "badge-success";} else {echo "badge-danger";}?>"><?php setJob($con, $id)?></span><?php
                    } ?>
                  </p>
                </a>
              </li><?php
            }
          ?>
```

Here is the PHP file where the setJob method is defined :

```php
<?php

function setJob($con, $idd) {

$sql = "SELECT status FROM mytable WHERE id=$id";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql); 
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) { 
    foreach ($row as $row => $value) { 
        echo $value; 
   }
}
} 
?>
```

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: There is many problems. 1. if you have many buttons, then you need to use `class` instead of `id`. 2. where is `data` attribute in your button? 3. you need to use passed `id` in php code for update.

Comment: Hello @Devsi, i have a question regarding "data attribute", could i then reference it with POST global method to access it afterwards in the WHERE clause in the sql query?

Comment: "i CANNOT link the ID of the clicked button" - why can't you do that? Have you tried it anywhere without success? Isn't that ID submitted via the `$_POST ` array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `data-id` attribute to add the id:

```html
<button id="submitbtn" data-id="<id>" type="button" class="btn btn-success">UPDATE</button>
```

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_data.asp

By default, jQuery ajax uses a `Content-Type` of `application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8`. This means in PHP the POST values can be accessed using [$_POST](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php). If using a `Content-Type` of `application/json`, you will need to do [this](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php#125651).

```php
include("src/db.php");

$id = $_POST['id']; // make sure to sanitize this value

$query = "UPDATE mytable SET job='completed' WHERE id=$id";

mysqli_query($conn, $query);
```

The above example only demonstrates how to reference the `id` value from the POST. However, this is not secure as-is. Make sure to sanitize the value as well as protect yourself from [SQL Injection](https://www.php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) using [prepared statements](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Prepared Statements allow you to bind variables to SQL queries which are sent separately to the database server and can not interfere with the query itself.

Comment: Could you give me more clarifications? how to access this in the WHERE clause..

Comment: Just edited my answer to demonstrate how to use the value.

Comment: Please do not reccomend the usage of insecure SQL queries. The given query is widely open for SQL injection and should **never** used in any script

Comment: Updated the example to include a comment about sanitizing the input.

Comment: @NicoHaase although my original example was insecure, it has been modified to touch on the point you are making. The original question included how to access the POST value in PHP, not how to protect from SQL Injection. With the revision, the user should at least be aware that the security problem exists.

Comment: Please share more details. Why should "value filtering" be used to avoid SQL injection?

Comment: Please be warned that this approach of "value filtering" might lead to new problems. When prepared statements are used, there's usually no need to modify the data further

Comment: @NicoHaase That is correct. Since prepared statements are the recommended approach, I removed the value filtering mention entirely.

Answer (score 0):

Updated HTML - added data-id="" to button and replace with id

```
<button id="submitbtn" data-id="<id>" type="button" class="btn btn-success">UPDATE</button>
```

Updated jQuery - use attr to get the id of row/record by using data-id attribute

```
  $('#submitbtn').on('click', function(){
    var id = $(this).attr('data-id');

    $.ajax({
        url: 'includes/updatequery.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {id:id},
        success: function(data){
            if (data) {
            console.log("updated");
            } else {
                $('#error').load("custom/static/error.html");
            }
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
            $('#error').html("oops" + errorThrown);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that other can learn from it. What did you change, and why?

Comment: added another class to the update button and same class used in jQuery for onclick functionality

Comment: Please add all clarification **to your answer** by editing it. Also, please explain why another class is needed - is there anything wrong with using an ID based selector, like in the original code?

Comment: id should be unique, and to calling Ajax by using ids more difficult if we use more ids

Comment: Why is AJAX "more difficult" if IDs are used? Usually, AJAx does not care about the markup it is triggered from, and using a class instead of an ID is only neccessary if such a button is used multiple times.

Comment: How can you call Ajax with many ids for same functionality

Comment: What do you mean by "with many ids"? The question contains only markup for a single button with a single ID. Also, feel free to add all clarification to your answer

Comment: for single record, we can use, updated my post, please check

Comment: Please add some explanation **to your answer** such that others can learn from it. This helps other to decide whether they want to use your approach or not

Comment: updated with comments